# login with twitter oauth via proxy

Tags: twitter, proxy, twitter-oauth

Look at this site:
http://premium.fluppy.me/oauthproxy/authorize?oauth_token=ac7FOow2Bj3N3Ob1O1FX0fRrCftwn3qj9lwMId7WQ

In this site you can login with twitter via proxy.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This website only get your user name and password and work like twitter client.

your request go to this server as proxy and then you see sever response.

just work like `PHProxy`

of course twitter has api for many easy work like tweet or follow somebody

see these examples:

- Best Twitter PHP Library - Stack Overflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422879/best-twitter-php-library
- Twitter Libraries | Twitter Developers -> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries
- tijsverkoyen/TwitterOAuth · GitHub -> https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/TwitterOAuth
- dg/twitter-php · GitHub -> https://github.com/dg/twitter-php
- themattharris/tmhOAuth · GitHub ->
  https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth